# Does anyone know a simple method for posting a tweet from within a WP7 app?

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, twitter, oauth, tweets

Im trying create a windows phone 7 application that allows the user to click a button and login to their twitter account and then using a text box send a basic tweet to their twitter account. Is there a simple method of doing this? Ive found a number of examples very hard to follow.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you have Twitter configured on the device, use the `ShareStatusTask`

```
var tsk = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ShareStatusTask();
tsk.Status = "Hello world!";
tsk.Show();
```

This also allows the user to post to Facebook / Windows Live / other social networks.  If you want to limit it to Twitter, you'll need to roll your own - possibly by launching a web browser to `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=your+encoded+message+text`

Comment: Is there any way to test this within the WP7 emulator to ensure that it would post to social networks in a real world scenario?

Comment: No, it isn't supported in the emulator because you can't add the required accounts.  Your best bet is to use a real device if you can.