# Why ShareStatusTask don't share status via twitter's app and ShareMediaTask I can share media?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, twitter

I'm trying share status in Windows Phone 8.1 via ShareStatusTask to Twitter's app and him don't appears in list of apps to share status.

See picture: (http://imgur.com/NVDoUXs,ZS2Ty9h#0)

But, when a I try share media via ShareMediaTask, "like a magic", him appears.

See picture: (http://imgur.com/NVDoUXs,ZS2Ty9h#1)

I can't understand the reason of this problem occurs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193868/does-anyone-know-a-simple-method-for-posting-a-tweet-from-within-a-wp7-app?rq=1) thread, if you do have `Twitter` configured within your device, then you should be able to view the `Twitter` option when using `ShareStatusTask`.

For more: [Windows Phone 7 ShareStatusTask - Is it possible to customize it further?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159020/)

Comment: I have configured Twitter app in my device, but when I try use ShareStatusTask, him don't available. I found in this link (http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/5853/cant-share-via-twitter) which Twitter change their oAuth service in Windows Phone 8.1. For that reason wp can't share status on twitter.

Comment: @YgorReis i guess it does happen for WP8.1 devices?

Comment: I can solved my problem using this code: 
WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
wbt.Uri = new Uri("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=" + tbox_status.Text, UriKind.Absolute);
wbt.Show();

Answer (score 0):

I can solved my problem using this code:

```
 


    WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
    wbt.Uri = new Uri("twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=" + tbox_status.Text, UriKind.Absolute);
    wbt.Show();
```